# "Merge" git repositories, "linking" commits

Tags: git, merge

I need to "merge" (not in the usualy git meaning) two repositories.  While doing that, I need to "link" (thankfully only few) commits together so that they stay in the end repository (with the same hash).  Time for a graph:

Status now:

```
project A has fileA, and commits:
a1 -> a2 -> a3

project B has fileB, and commits:
b1 -> b2 -> b3
```

I need:

```
projectAB with files A/fileA and B/fileB (so in subdirectories)
commits:

a1 -----> a2 -----> a3
 |         |         |
 |-> ab1 ->|-> ab2 ->|-> ab3 -> (development continues here)
 |         |         |
b1 -----> b2 -----> b3
```

How can I do that? I know that a commit [can have 3 (or more) parents](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/314215/65513), and I know about `git subtree`.

The important point is that the end repository needs to contain both the states of project A (e.g. commits a1, a2, a3, with only fileA) and project B (e.g. commits b1, b2, b3) with the same hash as they have now (to avoid messing up references to these commits).  Moreover I need to "state" as it is in ab1, ab2, ab3, not only ab3.

*Is there a better way than the following:*

1. Have two independent branches (a1... and b1...) in one repository
2. manually checking out a1, moving fileA to A/fileA, commit a1x
3. manually checking out b1, moving fileB to B/fileB, commit b1x
4. merge b1x and a1x to ab1
5. manually checking out a2, moving fileA to A/fileA, commit a2x
6. manually checking out b2, moving fileB to B/fileB, commit b2x
7. merge ab1, b2x and a2x to ab2
8. .. and so on ..

Comment: I'd really appreciate help with title and tags :)

Comment: You are implying here that `ax` is somehow parallel to `bx`. Is it so? They have to go parallel? Or something like `a1->a2->a3->b1->b2->b3` will also work?

Comment: Yes, they have to go in parallel. I basically need a "state" ab1, which has fileA from a1 and fileB from b1.  So "adding" b1 .. after a3 wouldn't give me that.

Comment: https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/ <- this looks kinda like what you are asking for

Comment: @dratenik Unfortunately not, this doesn't give me for example ab1, it just gives me a "state" like ab3 (although it of course preserves the history correctly, so I don't lose a1,...b1,...b3)

Comment: It does give you a way to have the a* and b* branch in the same repo, the ab* stuff you would have to generate from there.

Comment: Why do you need all these intermediate merged states?

Comment: @Schwern ab1 and ab2 are old versions which will need to get fixes backported from ab3. These fixes only work when A and B are "merged".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can approach this as a series of three way merges.

First, create the branch `dev.ab` where you'll build the ab series of commits, and initialize it with a merge of a1 and b1:

```sh
git checkout a1
git checkout -b dev.ab
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories b1
```

Now, `dev.ab` should point at the `ab1` state you want, except it won't have the files in the `A/` and `B/` directories as specified. That will probably require a number of `git mv` operations.

Then, do three way merges to bring in the next commits:

```
git merge a2 b2
```

and resolve any conflicts you get here, and move files as needed, to build `ab2`.

Then iterate:

```
git merge a3 b3
```

You should have the state you're after now, with the parentage to and a and b commits as you wanted it.

Comment: Hum, I see that I'm not handling a key part of your question, which is to have the A files in subdirectory `A/` and B files in `B/`. I would have to design and test a good solution and I don't have time just now, but I'm thinking after doing the first merge, run a bunch of `git mv` commands to put the files where you want them, before you do the next merge.

Comment: So far this is working fine (doing the mv as suggested, too) .. I'm currently dealing with conflicts due to files which are in both (and need to stay as copies for now), git is complaining that "we" moved file to A/file but "they" moved file to B/file.  This is a bit unrelated to the question, though.

Comment: For the first merge I had to use `--allow-unrelated-histories` though